# State Space invariance to a change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, control-theory, change-of-basis, linear-control

I've been trying to show an identity.

**Context:**

- $x$,$u$ are vectors
- $A$ has dimension $n\times n$ such that:
- $\dot{x}= Ax+Bu$
- $y= Cx +Du$

We can show that in Laplace domain:
$$G(s)= C(sI-A)^{-1}B + D$$
with $G(s)$ given by:
$$(Y(s)=G(s)*U(s))$$
That is simple.

The problem is that I can't convince myself that if I use $z=Tx$ we will have the same $G(s)$.
So that means: $$G(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B + D=CT^{-1}(sI-TAT^{-1})^{-1}TB + D$$
So the problem for me is to show this last identity, I lack of linear algebra knowledge to do that.
Thank you.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
A' = TAT^{-1}\\
B' = T B\\
C' = C T^{-1}\\
D'=D
$$

then

$$
C'(sI-A')^{-1}B'+D' = CT^{-1}(sT T^{-1}+TAT^{-1})^{-1}T B + D = CT^{-1}(T(sI-A)T^{-1})^{-1}TB+D
$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved, just used the property that the $T^{-1}M^{-1}T=(T^{-1}MT)^{-1}$. Thank you all.